# jqPlot DateAxisRenderer Strange Behaviour

Tags: jqplot

I have a fairly straightforward graph with a date axis. All the date data is in unix timestamp format.

When I render the graph without the DateAxisRenderer the graph appears as it should do...

[image: As expected:]
<sub>(source: [193.169.90.16](http://193.169.90.16/withoutdaterenderer.png))</sub>

...but when I add in the DateAxisRenderer...

[image: Not as expected]
<sub>(source: [193.169.90.16](http://193.169.90.16/withdaterenderer.png))</sub>

... the data points appear jumbled.

The only difference between these two graphs is the addition of the following lines...

```
renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
rendererOptions: { tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer },
tickInterval: '7 day',
tickOptions: { formatString: '%d %b' }
```

The whole thing is live [here](http://193.169.90.16/index.html).

Is this is a bug or am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Can you show us what the return JSON looks like?

Comment: {
     "min":1322697600000,
     "max":1325375999000,
     "data":[
      [
       [1322697600000,null],
       [1322784000000,null],
       [1322870400000,null],
       [1322956800000,null],
       [1323043200000,null],
       [1323129600000,null],
       [1323216000000,6.1614],
       [1323302400000,31.6241],
       [1323388800000,31.6241],
       [1323475200000,31.6241],
       ...

Comment: The whole file is here ... http://193.169.90.16/data.json. The graphs are here http://193.169.90.16/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DateAxisRenderer is choking on all the nulls in your input Array.  [If you take out those points it behaves](http://jsfiddle.net/XXBFu/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That does fix the problem. Seems like a bug though. Surely it should just skip empty data points in the same way that the default axis renderer does?

Comment: I agree it should be fixed in that renderer.  You should file a bug report: https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issues/